# YA novel maybe late 90s or early 00s about young woman who is the town outcast witch

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember the female character being a witch/healer.
Her family was outcast by the small town, a northeastern  setting maybe.
She falls for a fellow male student, who isn't exactly nice, and I believe he bullied her. 
I vaguely remember her being described wearing thrift store clothes/dresses. 
I honestly don't remember what the conflict was.

Very little information but it's been completely bugging me for some time now.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Answer (score 2):

*[Old Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/565595.Old_Magic)* by Marianne Curley

[image: Book Cover - Old Magic]

> Jarrod Thornton is mesmerizing, but Kate Warren doesn't know why.
>
> The moment the new guy walks into the room, Kate senses something strange and intense about him. Something supernatural. Her instincts are proven correct a few minutes later when, bullied by his classmates, Jarrod unknowingly conjures up a freak thunderstorm "inside" their classroom.
>
> Jarrod doesn't believe in the paranormal. When Kate tries to convince him that he has extraordinary powers that need to be harnessed, he only puts up with her "hocus pocus" notions because he finds her captivating. However, the dangerous, uncontrolled strengthening of his gift finally convinces Jarrod that he must take Kate's theories seriously. Together, they embark on a remarkable journey -- one which will unravel the mystery that has haunted Jarrod's family for generations and pit the teens against immense forces in a battle to undo the past and reshape the future.

Comment: You can accept your own answer within 48 hours of asking it. You just need to click on the green checkmark by the voting buttons.